# How to assign something to a variably named UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have 5 objects that i want to assign to UIImageViews named "obstacle1","obstacle2",etc. how can i do this in a for loop somewhat like this...

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    UIImageView "obstacle%d",i = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"square.png"]];

}
```

//the <"obstacle%d",i> part is what i need help with

Comment: Why do you think you need a local variable with a different name inside a `for` loop? BTW - spend time being detailed. If you don't have time to ask a decent question, no one will offer time to give a decent answer. :)

Comment: i need a local variable in a loop cuz i don't want to have repeat the same code just changing the UIImageView each time.

Answer (score 2):

You should really use an Array for holding your UIImageView objects:

```
NSMutableArray *imageViews = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    UIImageView *anObstacle = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"square%d.png",colorPick]]];
    [imageViews addObject:anObstacle];

}
```

Then you can just access them in the array by doing `imageViews[0]`.